# Equivalent of PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch() in log4j2?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am updating some software from log4j1 to log4j2. It uses [`PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(String configFilename, long delay)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch(java.lang.String,%20long)), for which I do not see any corresponding class or method in log4j2.

How do I update this to log4j2? What's the most straightforward way?

Do I have to make my own implementation of `configureAndWatch`, in a class inheriting from [`ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in the [log4j2 user's guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-users-guide.pdf).

[image]

So the `configureAndWatch` time can be set in the configuration file via the `monitorInterval` attribute.

Unfortunately this doesn't solve my situation as the `configureAndWatch` call I am trying to update to log4j2 occurs within a conditional. So though the `monitorInterval` attribute can be set in the properties file, I still do not see how to set the value conditionally based on runtime variables.